# Implementing encryption in Java whilst maintaining bitstring length

Tags: java, android, encryption, blowfish, bitstring

I'm trying to figure out a way of implementing Blowfish (or any encryption scheme that will work) in a program I am writing in Java for Android.

I have a sentence, like "I am a dog", which I want to encrypt.

However, before encryption, I encode the sentence with my own 5-bit character representations.

This is my own making, and is like a = "00110" and 'the' = "11001"

So now I have an encoding that is divisible by 5, and looks like

"00011101001101011010"

Is there a way to implement Blowfish to encrypt this binary string, whilst maintaining the length of the bit string.

i.e. the bit string above is 20 bits long. I want the encrypted bit string to also be 20 bits long.

Is this possible with Blowfish? Is it possible at all?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [Yes, it's possible](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44222/remove-blowfish-padding

Comment: I think you could use a block cipher as the key stream generator for a stream cipher like in CTR mode. I don't think you can ensure that the ciphertext would be the same length as the plaintext with a block cipher alone (e.g. without a CTR-like mode). Any reason why you're encoding the plaintext first? Seems kinda odd

Comment: @CommonsWare An even more clever solution is to use Format Preserving Encryption (FPE), usually used for credit card numbers and suchlike. I don't know why I didn't post it back then. Note that without some kind of unique input the ciphertext will not be unique either. So you either have to have a larger ciphertext or have deterministic encryption where sending the same ciphertext twice will produce identical results. I haven't seen many implementations in standard API's though.

Answer (score 1):

For any block cipher, the cipher text must be at least as big as the block size.  That is 64-bits for Blowfish, which means at least a 64-bit output.

If your plaintext is longer than your block size, then you can get the same cipher text size using cipher text stealing: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing

Not sure why you are doing the encoding that way, it certainly does not add to security.  Also, Blowfish is a dated algorithm: AES is a better choice, but that has block size 128.

Stream ciphers will allow you to get the exact same cipher text size as plaintext size, but I don't know of any good ones implemented in Java.  Whatever you do, stay away from rc4: it has real security problems.  See the [eSTREAM](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/) page for possible stream ciphers that should have adequate security.  Also, you must [never re-use a key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher_attack) for a stream cipher.

**EDIT**: @CommonsWare pointed out a [clever solution](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44222/remove-blowfish-padding) from Maarten Bodewes.  It looks correct to me, but I don't think you will find an implementation that does this out-of-the-box.  Keep in mind also that every ciphertext has to be paired with the IV, which is the same length as the block size (64-bits for blowfish).  You should never repeat an IV.  My general feeling is that although a clever solution, you're likely going to be better off if you do not have to implement something like this yourself (implementing crypto is dangerous: it is easy to lose security properties by making the smallest mistake).

Comment: Re: Stream ciphers.  Any block cipher, including Blowfish, can be used in counter mode (CTR mode) which is the equivalent of a stream cipher.  You will need to transfer a nonce as well as the cyphertext.  Twofish is more recent than Blowfish if you insist on not using AES.